# Struct compilation errors - dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to create a circular linked list, and im encounthering some errors.
Looks like the errors is talking about derefencing pointer, when im trying to access the Employee struct from inside the Node.

This is the errors I get:

```
 magic.c: In function ‘buildList’:
magic.c:49:2: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
 n->e.id = 1;
  ^
magic.c:53:4: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   n->e = e;
    ^
magic.c:54:4: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   n->d = d; 
    ^
magic.c:55:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   n = n->next = (ptr)malloc(sizeof(node)); 
        ^
magic.c:58:3: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  n->next = head;
   ^
magic.c:58:12: error: ‘head’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  n->next = head;
            ^
magic.c:58:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
magic.c: In function ‘printList’:
magic.c:68:17: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   printf("%d", n->e.id);
                 ^
magic.c:69:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   n = n->next;
        ^
make: *** [magic.o] Error 1
```

And this is my code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;

typedef struct {
    uint id;
    uint years;
    uint divion_id;
} employee;

typedef struct {
    uint id;
    char name[52];
    char manager_name[52];
    char telephone[16];
} division;

typedef struct node* ptr;

typedef struct {
    employee e;
    division d;

    ptr next;
} node;

typedef struct {
    ptr head;
} list;


list* buildList() 
{
    list *newList;
    uint i;
    employee e;
    division d;
    ptr n;

    e.id = 1;
    e.years = 5;
    e.divion_id = 1;

    newList = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    newList->head = (ptr)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n = newList->head;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        e.id = i+1;
        n->e = e;
        n->d = d;   
        n = n->next = (ptr)malloc(sizeof(node)); 
    }

    n->next = head;

    return newList;
}

void printList(list *lst) 
{
    ptr n = lst->head;

    do {
        printf("%d", n->e.id);
        n = n->next;
    } while (n != lst->head);
}




int main()
{
    list* lst;

    lst = buildList();
    printList(lst);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @juanchopanza - I am using the typedef PTR

Comment: Should the c++ tag be removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `typedef` of `ptr` you use the *structure* `node`, but you don't have such a *structure*, just a type-alias (a `typedef`).

Do e.g.

```
typedef struct node {
    ...
} node;
```

Comment: Ah yes. Watching too much football is making me blind.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I see it wrong is that you declare; typedef struct node* ptr; before declaring what is node, so you have to write typedef struct node* ptr; after node declaration..;
 not before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you have some kind of "incomplete type" deadlock scenario.
if we had deleted the `ptr` member inside the `node` structure like this:

```
typedef struct node* ptr;

typedef struct {
    employee e;
    division d;
} node;
```

then everything would have worked just fine. yes, it is true that `ptr` points to an incomplete type `struct node` but the `struct node` definition later, completes it.

the problem is that we have this:

```
typedef struct node* ptr;

typedef struct {
    employee e;
    division d;

    ptr next;
} node;
```

`ptr` points to the incomplete type `struct node` but when we define `struct node` later we find that `struct node` itself is incomplete because it contains a member of incomplete type `ptr` so it can't complete `struct node`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think that this is the cause for the compiler error and not the fact that we declare ptr when we dont have a structure called node. we do have structure node, the typedef here is not just type alias, it is type-alias + class declaration.